# How to upload documents by sending an email?

Tags: 2010

Is it possible to upload documents by sending an email to a specific email address & the documents are uploaded to a target Document Library?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this will answer your question:

> **Document libraries** : You can send documents as e-mail attachments to a
>   document library that is set up to
>   receive e-mail. There is no need to
>   switch to Windows SharePoint Services
>   3.0, search for the document, and then add it to the library. You can also
>   choose how the versions of a document
>   that are submitted through e-mail are
>   handled.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/add-content-to-sites-by-sending-e-mail-HA010086730.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Will it work for SP2010 also?

Comment: Yes, here's a link to the SharePoint 2010 instructions to setup email enabled document libraries.  https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/Pages/How-to-Setup-Mail-Enabled-Document-Libraries-in-SharePoint-2010-Part-4.aspx

Comment: Amazing! Thx Rob!

Answer (score 1):

1. **Enable incoming email on SharePoint**.

In SharePoint Central Administration, go to the Operations tab and click on “Incoming Email Settings.” Enable sites to receive email, leave the setting for Automatic mode, leave the setting for SharePoint Directory Management Service to No, add the subdomain you have chosen to the field for E-mail server display address:, and choose whether you want to accept email from any host, or if you want to enter the FQDN or ip.addr of each of your hub transport servers.

2. **Install the SMTP service on each of the SharePoint web front ends in
   your farm** (you may only have the one.)

This is a feature in Windows 2008. If you are not sure how to do this, see this article.

3. **Configure your Exchange infrastructure to forward email to your
   SharePoint infrastructure**.

On your Exchange server, launch the EMC. Browse down to the Organization Configuration and click Hub Transport. Click the action item for “New Send Connector” to launch the wizard. Name the connector, in the Address Space enter the FQDN of your chosen SharePoint email subdomain (sp.retrohack.com in my example above.) On the Network Settings, choose to Route Mail Through the Following Smart Hosts, and enter the FQDN or the ip.addr of the SharePoint WFE on which you installed the SMTP service. Leave the authentication and Source Server settings to default.

4. **Enable the document libraries and lists that you want to receive
   email**.

In SharePoint, browse to the list or document library you want to receive email, click on Settings, Document Library Settings, and configure the settings the way the SharePoint admin wants.

sources:

[How to Configure Exchange to Support Inbound Email for SharePoint](http://www.theemailadmin.com/2011/05/how-to-configure-exchange-to-support-inbound-email-for-sharepoint/)

[Configure incoming e-mail (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287879%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Add content to sites by sending e-mail](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-content-to-sites-by-sending-e-mail-b989a9f3-14de-4e59-9faf-b843ec40cabb?CorrelationId=bef5bfad-a38e-4aaa-bae9-27b152591baf&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

also i had the IncomingEmail.aspx not found error which resolved by Correct AAM ([source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e18abdc4-1c5e-4f7b-a33c-24ef93620ea7/incoming-mail-setup-file-not-found-error-after-2007-to-2010-upgrade?forum=sharepointadminprevious))